# Using guincorn with two workers, database connections are not released to connection pool. Why?

Tags: python, database, multithreading, gunicorn

Using guincorn with two workers, database connections are not released to the connection pool.

This works fine with one worker, but with two workers, the connections do not get released back to the pool and before long, the database throws a "too many connections" error.

I setup the flask app as below.  I am using gunicorn with these settings:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=2", "--threads=1", "--timeout=600", "-b 0.0.0.0:5000", "--preload", "wsgi:app"]
```

```
server.py
#Set up Flask:
app = Flask(__name__, 
            static_folder="web",
            template_folder="web")

# initialise classes
database = DatabaseManager() #database manager is responsible for the MySQL connection pool
...
```

Have been at this for a very long time and am out of ideas for what to try next.  Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, ```    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates',static_folder="web",)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 1200
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING'] = True
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
   @app.teardown_request
    def teardown_request(exception=None):
        if db is not None:
            db.session.close()
            db.engine.dispose()
```
Could u pls try this method